# How to concatenate a series to a pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I would like to iterate through a dataframe rows and concatenate that row to a different dataframe basically building up a different dataframe with some rows.

For example:
`[IPCSection and IPCClass Dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSx9U.png)

```
allcolumns = np.concatenate((IPCSection.columns, IPCClass.columns), axis = 0)
finalpatentclasses = pd.DataFrame(columns=allcolumns)
for isec, secrow in IPCSection.iterrows():
    for icl, clrow in IPCClass.iterrows():
        if (secrow[0] in clrow[0]):
            pdList = [finalpatentclasses, pd.DataFrame(secrow), pd.DataFrame(clrow)]
            finalpatentclasses = pd.concat(pdList, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
display(finalpatentclasses)
```

[The output is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gEuY.png)

I want the nan values to dissapear and move all the data under the correct columns. I tried axis = 1 but messes up the column names. Append does not work as well all values are placed diagonally at the table with nan values as well.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have figured it out. The idea is that you create a newrowDataframe and concatenate all the data in a list from there you can add it to the dataframe and then conc with the final dataframe.

Here is the code:

```
allcolumns = np.concatenate((IPCSection.columns, IPCClass.columns), axis = 0)
finalpatentclasses = pd.DataFrame(columns=allcolumns)
for isec, secrow in IPCSection.iterrows():
    for icl, clrow in IPCClass.iterrows():
        newrow = pd.DataFrame(columns=allcolumns)
                values = np.concatenate((secrow.values, subclrow.values), axis=0)
                newrow.loc[len(newrow.index)] = values 
                finalpatentclasses = pd.concat([finalpatentclasses, newrow], axis=0)
finalpatentclasses.reset_index(drop=false, inplace=True)
display(finalpatentclasses)
```

Update the code below is more efficient:

```
allcolumns = np.concatenate((IPCSection.columns, IPCClass.columns, IPCSubClass.columns, IPCGroup.columns), axis = 0)
newList = []
for secrow in IPCSection.itertuples():
    for clrow in IPCClass.itertuples():
        if (secrow[1] in clrow[1]):
            values = ([secrow[1], secrow[2], subclrow[1], subclrow[2]])
            new_row = {IPCSection.columns[0]: [secrow[1]], IPCSection.columns[1]: [secrow[2]],
                       IPCClass.columns[0]: [clrow[1]], IPCClass.columns[1]: [clrow[2]]}
            newList.append(values)
finalpatentclasses = pd.DataFrame(newList, columns=allcolumns)
display(finalpatentclasses)
```